# Import of csv to DB falsely appending # in front of _ (i.e. "_" -> "#_") - DataGrip Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am importing a csv from excel to a table in postgres through JetBrains DataGrip and the underscores are being imported with a hash sign in front of them like "#_".

For instance in the csv "foo_bar" goes to "foo#_bar".

When it shows the import preview, it does not show the # sign in front of the _.

When I view the column name, it doesn't show the # sign but when I count the characters, it counts the # even though it is not visible (i.e. "foo_bar" is displayed but counted as 8 characters, not 7)

The row entries all show the hash sign.

Would have thought others would have this problem as well. I have imported data plenty of times before with this functionality and everything was fine. This is new to me.

Comment: What version do you use? Must be fixed in 2071.1.2

Comment: @moscas I am on 2017.1 - I'll update and see if that fixed it - officially report this as a bug if not.

Comment: Please, write here if not.

Comment: @moscas You were exactly right - updating to the latest 2017.1.2 fixed the issue. Thanks!!!

Comment: Great! Follow @0xdbe twitter to stay tuned.